# How to get rid of free space in react-icons (bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to use the [react-icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/) but there's one problem. Every icon has weird margin at the top. How to get rid of this?

[image: icon]

EDIT:

```css
.mobileNavbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    @include yellow(background-color);
    @include red(color);
    width: 100%;
    position:sticky;
    bottom: 0;

    .icon {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    @media (min-width: $tablet) {
        .icon {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it still have this margin if you set the css to make the icon square?

Comment: This could be happening due to many reasons, try to post your code, or even better, a reproducible example on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @VictorAxelsson <svg> tag is square already but the div not.